# the configuration section 'services' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, web-config, wcf-binding

I have created a WCF service in Visual Studio 2012. When I started to debug it, the WCF test client showed the error:

"the configuration section 'services' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration"

This is not an IIS issue since I am using the WCF test client when I try to debug the service.

This is the whole web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework"
      type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
      requirePermission="false"/>
    <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client"
      type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <services>
    <service name="CodigoRFID.WS_RFID">
      <endpoint address="" contract="CodigoRFID.IWS_RFID" binding="basicHttpBinding"/>
      <endpoint address="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding"/>
    </service>
  </services>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
        type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="PEDIDO.SLLCOSTO" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
      connectionString="User Id=pedido;Password=uni_1915sll;Data Source=SLLCOSTO"/>
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Modelo.csdl|res://*/Modelo.ssdl|res://*/Modelo.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=SLLCOSTO;PASSWORD=uni_1915sll;USER ID=PEDIDO&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
      <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver"
        type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <publisherPolicy apply="no"/>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <dataSources>
        <dataSource alias="SLLCOSTO" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.2.34)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=REP)(SERVER=dedicated))) "/>
      </dataSources>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless this is a WCF Services section, you need to add a declaration for the `<services/>` section ... (What is this section for anyway? if it's supposed to be a WCF Services section, isn't that supposed to be inside a parent section named `<system.serviceModel>` ?
like this:

`<system.serviceModel>
     <services> [content here] </services>
     <behaviors> [content here] </behaviors >
     <bindings> [content here] </bindings >
</system.serviceModel>`

Otherwise, add the appropriate declaration:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
     <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit 
         http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework"
       type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection,
              EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
              PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
              requirePermission="false"/>
    <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client"
             type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler,
             Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral,
             PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    <section name="services" type="" />
```

etc.

except you need to fill in the type attribute properly

Comment: All those configurations were added automatically by the vs wizard when I created the project, so I cannot answer your questions.

Comment: What kind of Project did you create in Visual Studio?

Comment: It was "WCF Service Application"

Comment: I have seen that no wcf service uses configSections element, however, I am using EntityFramework and Odac. When I installed those libraries using Nuget, that section was added. In that case, I think the "services" definition should be present, so, how can I create the "services" definition? what type do I have to use?

Comment: I have just moved the "services" definition from the outer node to the serviceModel node and it worked. Strange that VS wizard added that in the incorrect part.

Comment: Yes, the `<system.serviceModel>` element, and the three contained elements `<services>`, `<behaviors>`, and `<bindings>`, are already declared within the .Net Framework, so you don't need to declare them yourself. Any custom configuration section, however, (which is what a `<services>` element would be), has to be declared, or the Configuration management code will not know what it is or how to de-serialize it.